# create table MariaDB

Tags: database, mariadb

## creating table in MariaDB

I want to create a table in MariaDB

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS match
(
    a INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    b INT NOT NULL,
    c INT NOT NULL,
    d INT NOT NULL,
    e INT NOT NULL,
    f INT NOT NULL,
    g VARCHAR(30)
)
```

but I got this error :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'match 
>   (
>       a INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
>       b INT NOT NULL,
>   ' at line 1 `

What is the problem?

Comment: [Reserved Words](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/reserved-words/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Match` is a reserved word ([`match against`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/match-against/) construction), so you cannot use it as table name. Check rule 18 here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/naming-rules/

Answer (score 2):

From maria db:

> #### Syntax
>
> MATCH (col1,col2,...) AGAINST (expr [search_modifier])

This construction is declared in the main language's structure so you cannot use the keyword `match` or any word that contains it.